# MVC4 Razor template like

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hello I have a simple question I think,

I have a cshtml like:

```
<div id="box">
    @if (model.View == "item1")
    {
        <div id="item1">
            ...
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div id="item2">
            ...
        </div>
    }   
    <div id="itemDescription">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I pass a parameter via the model to display some content depending on the parameter, because the rest of the document is the same in both cases.

Is there another better way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If there will be too much content in each of `item1` and `item2` then you better put them on partial views. In addition, you can create an html helper and let it decide which view to show and build/call the view.

Comment: Are you sure you want do that? Maybe it's working but it suck a bit ;p Adding anything would be pretty painful.

Comment: Yes I have made a partial view for each div, this is just a simple example. If I create an HtmlHelper I have to pass a parameter to it too I think, so would it have some advantages over the solution I have taken?

Comment: @gonzalomelov even with it you could end with situation where too much logic go to the view and if you mix it also with the logic in controller it goes painful ;->

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really; this is a perfectly good way of doing things. If the div id always matches the value of `model.View`, you could shorten it to this:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="@(model.View)">
        ...
    </div>  
    <div id="itemDescription">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, your approach is fine. As per von v's comment, you might want to look into partial views if the contained markup is long-winded (or you need to repeat the logic in multiple places):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/how-do-i-work-with-data-in-aspnet-mvc-partial-views

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I really don't like is passing the string parameter and comparing it in the view. However I can´t think in another better solution..

Comment: This is presentation logic, so the view is where it belongs. It's perfectly acceptable and in-keeping with the MVC paradigm to do things this way.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is fine if there **isn't much in those two `div`'s**. Otherwise, create two partial views to help keep things tidy:

```
@if (model.View == "item1")
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("Item1");
}
else
{
   @Html.RenderPartial("Item2");
}
```

Comment: +1 If partials are involved, this is a tidy example of how to pass data to them. I'd extrapolate on the question to suggest that something as simple as `@HtmlRenderPartial(model.View)` is probably fine, too.

Comment: Yes I have some partial views already. Like I commented, I don´t like the string comparision to choose to render some view. Thanks!